# How to assign a value of a property to a var ONLY if the object isn't null

Tags: c#, null

In my code, is there a shorthand that I can use to assign a variable the value of a object's property ONLY if the object isn't null?

```
string username = SomeUserObject.Username;     // fails if null
```

I know I can do a check like if(SomeUserObject != null) but I think I saw a shorthand for this kind of test.

I tried:

```
string username = SomeUserObject ?? "" : SomeUserObject.Username;
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: On the second, you're thinking of both the null coalescing operator *and* the conditional operator. Unfortunately, you've managed to combine them into illegal code. See the answers below for usage of the conditional operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax on the second is slightly off.

```
string name = SomeUserObject != null ? SomeUserObject.Username : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 7):

In c# 6.0 you can now do

```
string username = SomeUserObject?.Username;
```

username will be set to null if SomeUSerObject is null.
If you want it to get the value "", you can do

```
string username = SomeUserObject?.Username ?? "";
```

Comment: What if `username` is an existing variable with already a value and you want to overwrite the value ONLY if `SomeUserObject?.Username` is not null otherwise leave the existing value. Is there another shorter way than `username = SomeUserObject?.Username ?? username;` ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you're going to get, I think, is:

```
string username = SomeUserObject == null ? null : SomeUserObject.Username;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably as close as you are going to get:

```
string username = (SomeUserObject != null) ? SomeUserObject.Username : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ? : as others have suggested but you might want to consider the Null object pattern where you create a special static User `User.NotloggedIn` and use that instead of null everywhere.

Then it becomes easy to always do `.Username`.

Other benefits: you get / can generate different exceptions for the case (null) where you didn't assign a variable and (not logged in) where that user isn't allowed to do something.

Your NotloggedIn user can be a derived class from User, say NotLoggedIn that overrides methods and throws exceptions on things you can't do when not logged in, like make payments, send emails, ...

As a derived class from User you get some fairly nice syntactic sugar as you can do things like `if (someuser is NotLoggedIn) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of the ternary operator.

```
string username = SomeUserObject == null ? "" : SomeUserObject.Username;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx for more details.

Answer (score -1):

It is called null coalescing and is performed as follows:

```
string username = SomeUserObject.Username ?? ""
```

Comment: Will still fail if SomeUserObject is null.

Comment: SomeUserObject could be null. He should be using the conditional operator and checking his object for null.